# ESLINT with --fix option not fixing my js files

Tags: node.js, eslint

My eslint configuration is as simple as this

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb-base",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jquery": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "ejs"
  ]
}
```

when I run

```
eslint app.js
```

the output is  :

```
  162:110  error    A space is required after ','                                                                  comma-spacing
  167:1    error    Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4                                                   indent
  168:1    error    Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8                                                   indent
  169:1    error    Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8                                                   indent
  170:1    error    Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4                                                   indent
  171:1    error    Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8                                                   indent
  171:9    warning  Unexpected console statement                                                                   no-console
  172:1    error    Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8                                                   indent
  173:1    error    Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12                                                  indent
  174:1    error    Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12                                                  indent
  175:1    error    Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8                                                   indent
  176:11   error    Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4                                                   indent

✖ 131 problems (116 errors, 15 warnings)
  102 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

It says 102 errors are fixable with --fix but when I run with `eslint app.js --fix`  It fixed nothing. It is showing the same output. Why --fix is not able to fix anything?

## **UPDATE**

When I removed the ejs from plugins, it is working fine. But still, dont understand what is the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Try adding extension type flags? e.g., `--ext .js,.jsx`

Comment: What ESLint version are you using too? `eslint --version` should tell you. Try the `--debug` flag, and for more readable output use in tandem with `--format json`

Comment: @NickBull  eslint version is v5.9.0

Comment: @NickBull, I tried adding extension type flag on execution, still no luck.